# XML alternative for setDrawerLockMode

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout, navigationview, android-navigationview

I would like to set [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout)'s lock mode to `DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED` but I want to do it using XML properties **NOT** programatically. Somewhat just like the invalid XML below:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:lock_mode = "close"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

*NOTE:* The XML code `android:lock_mode = "close"` does not exist.